# OpenGL: how to render outside of a texture's region

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to implement a shader that can round the corners of a texture, and apply a border around it. This would be used in a window manager to have rounded windows with borders around them. The current fragment shader is as shown below (pardon the formatting).

```
const GLchar surface_fragment_src_rgba[] = 
 "precision mediump float;\n" 
 "varying vec2 v_texcoord;\n" 
 "uniform sampler2D tex;\n" 
 "\n" 
 "uniform vec2 half_size;\n" 
 "uniform vec2 position;\n" 
 "uniform float alpha;\n" 
 "uniform float radius;\n" 
 "uniform float half_border_thickness;\n" 
 "uniform vec4 border_color;\n" 
 "\n" 
 "float RectSDF(vec2 p, vec2 b, float r) {\n" 
 "   vec2 d = abs(p) - b + vec2(r);\n" 
 "        return min(max(d.x, d.y), 0.0) + length(max(d, 0.0)) - r;\n" 
 "}\n" 
 "\n" 
 "void main() {\n" 
 "        vec2 center = gl_FragCoord.xy - position - half_size;\n" 
 "        float dist = RectSDF(center, half_size + half_border_thickness, radius - half_border_thickness);\n" 
 "\n" 
 "        vec4 tex_color  = texture2D(tex, v_texcoord) * alpha;\n" 
 "   vec4 from_color = border_color;\n" 
 "   vec4 to_color   = vec4(0.0);\n" 
 "        if (half_border_thickness > 0.0) {\n" 
 "                if (dist < 0.0) {\n" 
 "                        to_color = tex_color;\n" 
 "                }\n" 
 "                dist = abs(dist) - half_border_thickness;\n" 
 "        } else {\n" 
 "                from_color = tex_color;\n" 
 "        }\n" 
 "\n" 
 "        float blend_amount = smoothstep(-1.0, 1.0, dist);\n" 
 "        gl_FragColor = mix(from_color, to_color, blend_amount);\n" 
 "}\n";
```

I have a mockup [on shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/st3BR8).

I am pretty confident that the shader works as intended, but my problem is that the shader doesn't operate outside of the original bounds of the texture. As an example, [this is what it looks like when rendering a window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrazn.jpg). If anyone knows how I can render the region of the window plus the borders please let me know!

As a side note, if this is a suboptimal way to go about this, please let me know :) Originally, I rendered borders with a separate shader, but I figured I'd need knowledge of the texture's colors to blend the borders for antialiased rounded corners.

Comment: You said "outside of a texture's region" twice, and shown a screenshot of what looks like a window manager. After reading that I still have no idea what you're trying to describe.

Comment: "if this is a suboptimal way to go about this" -- it absolutely is, branching in shaders is incredibly inefficient. Render your corners to a texture and use quads to draw your window frame and background.

Comment: @Blindy apologies for the confusion, as you can tell I'm relatively new to openGL. Essentially the only area that I can see the borders render is in the corner of the window, which is inside of the area that the texture of the window encompasses. The border isn't rendering around the window, which I assume is due to them being outside of the area of the window texture based on my corner observation.

Comment: @Blindy I really appreciate the suggestion! I had tried a similar approach to that but had trouble blending the border corner with the window corner, which can be seen in the faint white line between the window and border here: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35975961/188004011-e788af59-a810-447c-987b-73f2c4d3c2b7.png any idea how to blend the two?

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do, what is that windowing manager? Is it yours? Is it some kind of Linux distribution? If it's yours then simply render more than just your window, if it's an actual X server window then render the frame inside the window, define the corners as transparent (no idea how you'd do that in Linux) and reduce your window's client size (same).

Comment: As to the faint white line, simply render better. Figure out if it's because you're doing linear and/or mipmap filtering on the texture, or if you're just rendering garbage in the first place. I lost count of how many times I've said this, but you really don't give me much to work with here but some screenshots with very little background. Screenshots aren't debugging.